# Strange behavior of Ext.Date.add component

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5, sencha-architect

I have a problem with

> Ext.Date.add

When I add days:

```
var someDate = new Date(2021, 9, 30);
var startDate = Ext.Date.add(someDate, Ext.Date.DAY,  1);
var endDate = Ext.Date.add(someDate, Ext.Date.DAY,  2);
```

the values `start` and `end` are the same. Why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `true` and now everything works fine:

```
var startDate = Ext.Date.add(someDate, Ext.Date.DAY,  1, true);
var endDate = Ext.Date.add(someDate, Ext.Date.DAY,  2, true);
```

Comment: What version a you using?

Answer (score 0):

The method works correctly in my case. look at my [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/351t)